Loading src with nextjs/script
So we have a webmaster that has a JS Block in our CMS where they can load some JavaScript. So they have some dynamic 365 forms with is loaded with nexts/script and the src comes from the CMS content. The form renders fine on first page load. If I navigate to another page and back again, it does not render det form. Looks like it caches the script and then don’t load it again and the form is not loaded inside the div with the right is as on first render. Is there some way to make that work?

Are there any props which your form requires to load properly but does not receive when you move back to the page? Also, how are you moving back to the page? Are you using the browser's back button or simply re-opening the form?

Det only prop is the url to the dynamics 365 script. And that prop is used as src in the script tag. I just navigate true the site navigation. Reloading the page also makes it work. So it’s like nextjs knows the script from cache. Even putting a date now time stamp in the url don’t help.
